# Restriction on use of display names?

Tags: discussion

What if someone changes their display name to Moderator or Site Administrator or something else which expresses a kind of authority on the site ?

I know it's misuse can be detected and dealt with but is it not better to have them reserved once and forever.

Comment: [You can recognize moderators by the diamond after the display name](http://superuser.com/help/site-moderators) (last paragraph; it also has a _moderator_ tooltip), and that's actually protected by the system. Someone giving themselves the name _Moderator_ really means nothing, just like someone writing in their _About_ text that they're a moderator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally we don't place restrictions on usernames because to restrict specific words can be counter-productive and easily circumvented.

If we ban the word "moderator" then it can be circumvented by writing "mơderator" or a thousand variations of such that is hard to spot or ban specifically.

It also isn't worthwhile to ban someone from using specific words because it is entirely possible that they are legitimately using the word, but not in the context of *this* site.  It is possible that they could have the username "SiteName_Moderator_Bob" if they are trying to support users from their own site.

Essentially blocking the rare specific word abuse wont prevent someone who is actively trying to make use of the word and only harms those with a legitimate reason to do so, and is a painful and arduous process to implement and keep up to date.

It's a lot easier to just deal with the rare case of abuse than to maintain an entire massive dictionary or banned words and their various misspellings.